# X509Certificate2 from inside an Azure function app - The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I am trying to create an X509Certificate2 from inside an Azure function app. It works perfectly well from my own machine with the same credentials;

```
ver cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes, "passcode");
```

However, when run inside a function app the following exception occurs

```
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore>
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
```

Is this some kind of permissions issue? There is no certificate store

Comment: Just curious, does the certificate object contain private key? Can you check `HasPrivateKey` and `PrivateKey` properties of `X509Certificate2` object?

Comment: yes it does have a private key

Comment: Then it seems that remote party don't trust your certificate.

Comment: I think the problem is WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE=1, even though the certificate is built on the fly the user profile needs to be loaded

Comment: Having the same issue with azure. did this solution work for you?

Comment: Rod made my day. The Website_load_user_profile worked
Thank you Rod